# How to extract complete information from QuickOSM

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, network, quickosm

I am trying to extract information from Quick OSM about the electricity grid in my country. As a key in QuickOSM I enter power, but the information I receive is not complete. On the map I see that there is a power grid that is not included in the QuickOSM results.
I'm attaching an image to the card I'm talking about.
[image: electricity gird in Bulgaria]

With a pink line is the result obtained from QuickOSM (right). An unmarked power transmission road can be seen on the left.
In the same way I set criteria for searching for solar farms, but it is clear from the map that not all of them are marked.
Is there a way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the openstreetmap web page for this area and zoom in, you can click on a feature and get all its tags. eg here I've clicked on a power line and selected it and here's its tag view:

[image]

from that you should be able to work out what tags you need to search for in QuickOSM or you might discover it has been tagged wrongly in which case you can go to the OSM web page and edit it for corrections.

The OSM web query tool icon is the one with the question mark at the bottom of the tool bar and shows nearby and enclosing features (note it is only active at high zoom levels)

[image]